# How to Convert JSON File data from Azure API into CSV?

Tags: json, azure, powershell, api, csv

I have a JSON file which has the data shown below, and I am trying to convert it into CSV using the Powershell Script but the response I am getting is unexpected. How Will I get the data of timestamp, average and maximum values correctly in csv columns.

```
JSON data:

[
    {
        "cost":  44639,
        "timespan":  "2023-02-10T23:59:59Z/2023-03-13T23:59:59Z",
        "interval":  "PT1H",
        "value":  [
                      {
                          "id":  "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/Automation-script/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/automationscript87c1/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/UsedCapacity",
                          "type":  "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
                          "name":  {
                                       "value":  "UsedCapacity",
                                       "localizedValue":  "Used capacity"
                                   },
                          "displayDescription":  "The amount of storage used by the storage account. For standard storage accounts, it\u0027s the sum of capacity used by blob, table, file, and queue. For premium storage accounts and Blob storage accounts, it is the same as BlobCapacity or FileCapacity.",
                          "unit":  "Bytes",
                          "timeseries":  [
                                             {
                                                 "metadatavalues":  [

                                                                    ],
                                                 "data":  [
                                                              {
                                                                  "timeStamp":  "2023-02-10T23:59:00Z"
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                  "timeStamp":  "2023-02-11T00:59:00Z"
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                  "timeStamp":  "2023-02-11T01:59:00Z"
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                  "timeStamp":  "2023-02-11T02:59:00Z", 
                                                                  "average" : 17044123
                                                              }
                                                 
                                                          ]
                                             }
                                         ],
                          "errorCode":  "Success"
                      }
                  ],
        "namespace":  "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "resourceregion":  "centralindia"
    },
    
    
        "cost":  44639,
        "timespan":  "2023-02-10T23:59:59Z/2023-03-13T23:59:59Z",
        "interval":  "PT1H",
        "value":  [
                      {
                          "id":  "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/VM-DavePlatform_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/AnotherTestVM/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Percentage CPU",
                          "type":  "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
                          "name":  {
                                       "value":  "Percentage CPU",
                                       "localizedValue":  "Percentage CPU"
                                   },
                          "displayDescription":  "The percentage of allocated compute units that are currently in use by the Virtual Machine(s)",
                          "unit":  "Percent",
                          "timeseries":  [
                                             {
                                                 "metadatavalues":  [

                                                                    ],
                                                 "data":  [
                                                              {
                                                                  "timeStamp":  "2023-02-10T23:59:00Z"
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                  "timeStamp":  "2023-02-11T00:59:00Z"
                                                              },
                                                              {"timeStamp":  "2023-03-13T21:59:00Z",
                                                               "maximum" 35.16
                                                              }
                                                          ]
                                             }
                                         ],
                          "errorCode":  "Success"
                      }
                  ],
        "namespace":  "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "resourceregion":  "centralindia"
    } ]
```

Powershell Script

```
  # Load the JSON file
    $json = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Downloads\All_Resources_Combined.JSON" | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    # Select the properties you want to keep and convert the values to string
    $json | Select-Object @{n='Id';e={$_.value.id}},
                                   @{n='LocalizedValue';e={$_.value.name.localizedValue}},
                                   @{n='Unit';e={$_.value.unit}},
                                   @{n='Timestamp';e={$_.value.timeseries.data | ForEach-Object {$_.timeStamp}}},
                                   @{n='Average';e={$_.value.timeseries.data | ForEach-Object {$_.average}}},
                                   @{n='Maximum';e={$_.value.timeseries.data | ForEach-Object {$_.maximum}}} |
            Export-Csv  "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Downloads\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqzuV.png)

I have tried iterating my Powershell script for each timestamp but still I am not getting the data of each timestamp for every row instead getting all the timestamp values in a single row.

Comment: what your expected result supposed to look like?

Comment: I want all the timestamps in separate rows for each particular time value

Comment: You've asked 9 questions so far, accepted an answer to just one of them, while providing little to no feedback on the answers to your other questions. If any of those answers solved your problems, they should be accepted too - it is an important signal to future readers (albeit not the only one - up-votes may ultimately count more). If none of those answers solved your problem, providing feedback on how they fell short at least has a chance of leading to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop over each object's `.value.timeseries.data.timestamp` property values in order to create an output object for each.

Building on your approach (if performance is a concern, this could be optimized):

```bash
Get-Content -Raw C:\Users\$env:UserName\Downloads\All_Resources_Combined.JSON | 
  ConvertFrom-Json | 
  ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($ts in $_.value.timeseries.data.timestamp) {
       $_ | 
         Select-Object @{n = 'Id'; e = { $_.value.id } },
           @{n = 'LocalizedValue'; e = { $_.value.name.localizedValue } },
           @{n = 'Unit'; e = { $_.value.unit } },
           @{n = 'Timestamp'; e = { $ts } },
           @{n = 'Average'; e = { $_.value.timeseries.data.average } } },
           @{n = 'Maximum'; e = { $_.value.timeseries.data.maximum } } } 
    }
  } # | Export-Csv ...
```

Note the use of [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) above, in the property-access expressions `.value.timeseries.data.timestamp`, `.value.timeseries.data.average`, and `.value.timeseries.data.maximum`.